# mysql Connector J version 8 not working with JPA eclipse Entities generation

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jpa, jdbc

I recently updated mysql server, workbench and all the packages to the newest version using the mysql installer. It changed the mysql connector Jar from version 5.1 to 8.0.

I configured the JAR deployed on my application server(wildfly) to the new connector, then I did the same in eclipse because I started a new JPA project and I need the "Generate Entities from Tables".

When I click it, it shows my the window in which I can configure the connection to the database. So I Add a new mysql connection and I specify a driver using the template.

First Problem: in the "Specify a Driver Template and Definition Name" window there is NO MySQL JDBC Driver version 8, but 5.1. I used it but I specified the connector version 8.0.

In my opinion the previous step was the problem..

When I finish to configure my connection I can choose the entities to generate and the table associations. Well the problem is: there are no table associations specified... I've done this generation step many times and this problem never happened. In addiction to this, when I generate my entities they're totally wrong: fields duplicated everywhere, associations not mapped with annotations, fields'names in part wrong...

So:
Does the version 8.0 has a problem or do I have to configure something else?
I already added a new connector through: Window -> Preferencies, Data Management → Connectivity → Driver Definitions -> Add button.
But nothing.

Just for completeness, I've created a simple db following these steps and I launched some queries in jpql and it worked: they show the data in the db. I seriously need this generation step to work, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: As you cannot choose 8.0 why do you think this should work? Which Eclipse version do you use?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I thought it was possible because the options are just templates, not forced choices. I can perfectly choose version 8 and it doesn't give an error. Eclipse, mysql, wildfly, maven and everithing else are all up to the latest version: i downloaded eclipse photon 2 days ago

Comment: I don't know what have changed from a meta data perspective in 8. So the question is why don't you just use 5.1 to generate the entites?

Comment: it is not my intention to use always the most updated version, but if you download mysql from the official site the recommended option is version 8, so I thought it was safe and more efficient to upgrade. it is an official stable version, so I think it is a problem with my configuration or my tool.

Comment: but with 5.1 it works as expected?

Comment: yes, perfectly. I think I'll go with it but it's wrong to use an old version just because the newer one doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is probably on the Eclipse side so you must use what Eclipse is supporting.

Answer (score 1):

It works, follow these steps:

- download 8.0.XX jar file from mysql sight (connector /j)
- extract the jar file, and copy it to lib director under web-inf (j2ee)
  from data source explorer
- righ click database connection and select new
- select mysql and update settings

You could get the connection to the database mysql using connector 8.0

Answer (score -1):

There is a bug selecting the MySQL template for MySQL driver 8 - issue [HAL-1516](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/HAL-1516) on the issue tracker.